# Thread.join() not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm using a thread to repaint a JPanel (seeing as `repaint()` is thread safe).

Here is the paintComponent method:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Print statement so I know where my program is at.
    System.out.println("Repainting world...");
    g.drawImage(worldImage, x, y, 6144, 4608, null);
}
```

I have a thread that starts inside of a `KeyListener` whenever a user presses a certain button

Run method:

```
public void run(){
                game.repaint();
}
```

Lastly, here's my calls to the thread that uses the above run method:

```
//NOTE: I've tried this without the if statement, made no difference
if(!gameThread.isAlive()){
    gameThread.start();
    try {
            gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that, with this case (since it's in a `KeyListener)`, `Thread.join()` stops the `EDT` until that run method is executed.

The problem is, `Thread.join` is throwing an `InterruptedException` whenever I press the button again, no matter how long I wait. This leads me to believe that somewhere it's getting hung in an area, where the thread will not stop it's execution. I just can't tell where it could potentially be getting hung up.

Comment: You can't start a thread several times. Is that what you're doing? Why are you calling join() in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? Please provide a complete minimal program reproducing the problem.

Comment: Also, why are you using a background thread to make a single call to `repaint()`? This makes no sense since you usually use background threading to call long-running code, such as long-running loops, and not to make a single call to a method. Please explain the details of your program set up, what you're trying to achieve with all of this because I have a feeling that you might want to re-structure this program. It looks like you want to create a game loop of some kind, but neglected to put any loop in the background thread, or to use a Swing Timer (my choice if this were mine).

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to repaint 2 components on separate occasions, but they both repaint inside of a `KeyListener`, which means both are queued on the `EDT` which makes it update slowly, and makes it very choppy. From what googling things showed me, it seemed like Thread.join() will stop a thread, if it doesn't then I need to know how to stop one (since `Thread.interrupt` is generally frowned upon). After they hit a button, I do call `Thread.start()` again, yes.

Comment: Sorry, but your use of threading is way off here and won't solve anything. Again, consider using a Swing Timer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Doesn't a timer queue on the `EDT`?

Comment: Yes it does, but again, using a background thread to call a single `repaint()` will waste a lot of resources unnecessarily and will only slow things down, not speed them up.

Comment: Rather than have us chase an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: And your thread doesn't need "stopping". It only calls a method once and then it ends.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But if I'm already executing it through the `EDT` how would adding a timer make it faster than just not using any threads at all? I will, however, take your suggestion and try out a timer (Since the answer below made it clear that repaint will **always** run on the `EDT` (the thing I was trying to get around via multiple threads))

Comment: It's all about perceived responsiveness. The Timer will allow you to make calls on the EDT with time slices, and the slices won't block the EDT which is key, since a Timer uses background threading behind the scenes. For what it's worth, the "accepted" answer to this question is not correct about join blocking in this situation, since your thread is already dead, but it's your question, and yours to decide. There can be no "correct" answer to this question in its current incomplete state.

Comment: It's not the solution, but it answers the general question (The last sentence I wrote) i.e. "I just can't tell where it could potentially be getting hung up."

Comment: If you need better help, improve the question -- create and post your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describe the behavior you're trying to achieve, not how you're trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this...you're calling repaint() from within your gameThread. Since repaint() executes on the EDT, I think you've blocked it from executing by virtue of the fact that gameThread.join() blocks the EDT (since it's started by the EDT i.e. from within your KeyListener handler).